# How to use websoket with spring cloud (Micro-services) ?

Tags: spring, microservices

i have created micro-service project and need to integrate with WebSocket

Answer (score 1):

The book [Spring Boot Messaging: Messaging APIs for Enterprise and Integration Solutions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484212258) chapter 7 (Using WebSockets with Spring) explains how to and provides good examples. If you're looking for code examples for a particular scenario within the answer in stackoverflow, then please narrow down the scope of the question as it is too broad.